# Formatting Disappear when Deploying the Events of Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am currently working on an homework assignment of matplotlib. The assignment is about deploying the events handling mechanism.

I have successfully completed the refresh part for the graph. However, I notice that after refreshing, the previous formatting like title, axis labels and spine settings in the code cannot be redrawed in the new graph.

I have searched for a while but could not find the reason and the respective solution.

The simplified code is as below. Is there any help?

```
def plot_bar(yvalue=None):

    if yvalue is None:
        yvalue = 400

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.bar([1, 2, 3], [300, 500, 400], color=['r', 'g', 'b'],
           width=1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.8)

    ax.axhline(yvalue, color='grey', linewidth=1.5)

    ax.set_title('Reference y Value: {:d}'.format(yvalue))
    ax.set_xlabel('Year')
    ax.set_ylabel('Mean Value (with CI)')
    ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3])
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

    return None

def onclick(event):

    plt.clf()
    plot_bar(yvalue=event.ydata)

    return None

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
plot_bar()
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: Add a pause, `plt.pause(0.001)`, at the end of your `plot_bar` function just before you return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried, but it does not seem to work.